# a div where you destroy elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
$(".drop").sortable({
connectWith: 'ul',
cancel: ".ui-state-highlight"
});
$(".draggable").draggable({
connectToSortable: '.drop',
helper: 'clone',
revert: 'invalid',
editable: true
});

$("#test").disableSelection();
```

i create (clone) elements by dragging then to the the list, so i want to create a div "REMOVE HERE" so when the user drags one of these clonned elements, it would just be removed

how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [jQuery UI Photo Manager](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager) script.